# Scrapy - unexpected unindent for "yield" command

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a silly question that doesn't let me run the spider. Every time I run the spider, I get `IndentationError` for the last "}" at the end of my spider code after "yield" and I cannot find out WHY. Can someone help me out with the problem? Thanks a lot!!

Here is my spider:

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
import scrapy
import json
import logging
import urlparse


class ArtsPodcastsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'arts_podcasts'
    allowed_domains = ['www.castbox.fm']
    

    def start_requests(self):
        
        try:
            if response.request.meta['skip']:
                skip=response.request.meta['skip']
            else:
                skip=0
                
            while skip < 201:
                url = 'https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip=0&limit=60&web=1&m=20201112&n=609584ea96edb64605bca96212128aa5&r=1'
                split_url = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
                path = split_url.path
                path.split('&')
                path.split('&')[:-5]
                '&'.join(path.split('&')[:-5])
                parsed_query = urlparse.parse_qs(split_url.query)
                query = urlparse.parse_qs(split_url.query, keep_blank_values=True)
                query['skip'] = skip
                updated = split_url._replace(path='&'.join(base_path.split('&')[:-5]+['limit=60&web=1&m=20201112&n=609584ea96edb64605bca96212128aa5&r=1', '']),
                    query=urllib.urlencode(query, doseq=True))
                updated_url=urlparse.urlunsplit(updated)
                
                
                yield scrapy.Request(url= updated_url, callback= self.parse_id, meta={'skip':skip})
    
                def parse_id(self, response):

                    skip=response.request.meta['skip']
                    data=json.loads(response.body)
                    category=data.get('data').get('category').get('name')
                    arts_podcasts=data.get('data').get('list')
                    for arts_podcast in arts_podcasts:
                        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip={0}&limit=60&web=1&m=20201111&n=609ba0097bb48d4b0778a927bdcf69f4&r=1'.format(arts_podcast.get('list')[2].get('cid')), meta={'category':category,'skip':skip}, callback= self.parse)


                def parse(self, response):

                    skip=response.request.meta['skip']
                    category=response.request.meta['category']
                    arts_podcast=json.loads(response.body).get('data')
                    yield scrapy.Request(callback=self.start_requests,meta={'skip':skip+1})
                    yield{

                        'title':arts_podcast.get('title'),
                        'category':arts_podcast.get('category'),
                        'sub_category':arts_podcast.get('categories')
                        }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is having a `try` without a matching `except` or `finally`.

I would expect this to result in `SyntaxError`, but I'm guessing python detects that you're back to the original indentation of the `try` statement before it figures out there is no matching `except`/`finally`.

There are other errors, such as accessing unexistant `response` in `start_requests` and parsing methods' indentation being wrong...